# nginx no live upstreams while connecting to upstream https

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to proxy api requests to remote api server (https://api.domain.com)
That's my nginx config

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name dev.domain.com;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass https://api.domain.com;

        }
```

But I got error

```
no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: dev.domain.com, request: "GET /api/current_ip HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://api.domain.com/api/current_ip", host: "dev.domain.com", referrer: "https://dev.domain.com/api/current_ip"
```

I don't understand what is missed in my config.

Answer (score 3):

You try to request url using `http` and proxy pass `https`, you'll need to add SSL configuration, when is done you have to put `location /api/` before `location /`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;       # to remove, You will need to setup SSL
        listen [::]:80 default_server;  # to remove, You will need to setup SSL

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_....
        ...

        server_name dev.domain.com;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location /api/ {      ## Put this first
                proxy_pass https://api.domain.com;
        }
  
        location / {          ## Put this always at the end (is like a *wilcard)
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
}
```

If you want to reverse proxy something using TLS, you have to provide TLS too.

At some point it'll be better to hace a standalone config only for this reverse proxy with `https`